# C# WinForms - ListViewItem image not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, listviewitem

I have a rather trivial problem with image not showing up for each `ListViewItem`. There should be an image next to each service name, but none shows up. `Application.EnableVisualStyles();`  is turned on. I tried setting resource images to `PictureBox` as a test and that works ok. Both column headers were added in designer. Indexes get correctly set for each item, also tried with assigning `ImageKey`.

Already read multiple similar questions on here, but none solve this problem.

Initialization of ImageList done on load

```
    ImageList serviceLogoList = new ImageList
    {
        ImageSize = new Size(32, 32),
        ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
    };

    serviceLogoList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.drive_logo);
    serviceLogoList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.dropbox_logo);
    serviceLogoList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.seeyou_logo);

    listViewDisablableItemsServices.View = View.Details;
    listViewDisablableItemsServices.LargeImageList = serviceLogoList;
    listViewDisablableItemsServices.SmallImageList = serviceLogoList;
```

Assigning the images to each row

```
foreach (var service in _services)
{
    if (service.ServiceType == Constants.SERVICE_TYPE_STORAGE)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(service.Label);
        item.SubItems.Add(service.ErrorOrInterpretedError ?? Lang.GetString("Common_OK"));
        item.Tag = service;

        switch (service.ServiceName)
        {
            case "google":
                item.ImageIndex = 0;
                break;
            case "dropbox":
                item.ImageIndex = 1;
                break;
            case "seeyou":
                item.ImageIndex = 2;
                break;
        }

        listViewDisablableItemsServices.Items.Add(item);

        if (!service.IsAuthenticatedAndAvailable)
        {
            listViewDisablableItemsServices.DisableItem(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Where images should show up

[image: Location of images]

Comment: Did you set the LargeImageList or SmallImageList  of the LV?

Comment: hi, I am just guessing here, but I do not see a link between your ImageList object and the for loop. Shouldnt you access your images through the ImageList in the for loop?

Comment: ImageList is set in the initialization part of code. It can then be accessed via index. listViewDisablableItemsServices.LargeImageList = serviceLogoList;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing and then re-adding the `ListView` component in my original code solved the issue. Also the Visual Studio has been restarted after re-adding it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a similar winform project and it works.

My sample code:

```cs
ImageList serviceLogoList = new ImageList
{
    ImageSize = new Size(32, 32),
    ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
};

serviceLogoList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.p1);
serviceLogoList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.p2);

listViewDisablableItemsServices.View = View.Details;
listViewDisablableItemsServices.LargeImageList = serviceLogoList;
listViewDisablableItemsServices.SmallImageList = serviceLogoList;


ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("test1");
item1.ImageIndex = 0;
item1.SubItems.Add("XD1");

ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("test2");
item2.ImageIndex = 1;
item2.SubItems.Add("XD2");

listViewDisablableItemsServices.Items.Add(item1);
listViewDisablableItemsServices.Items.Add(item2);
```

I think your `switch` not be entered to set `ImageIndex`. You can add Debug to check `ImageIndex` is set or not.

Comment: Already checked that and ImageIndex gets correctly assigned in the switch. Also tried hardcoding the same index for all rows.

Comment: @tomazj have you tried other images as your resources? Randomly pick some pictures from Google Image and set them in ImageList.

Comment: Makes no difference. Tried a couple images, formats, same result. At least I know, there is apparently problem elsewhere.

Comment: If you create a simple project like my sample, will it work? Check some environment factors...

Comment: Yes, the images then show. Will check environment params.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing adding the Columns

```
listViewDisablableItemsServices.Columns.Add("Name",100);
listViewDisablableItemsServices.Columns.Add("Status",100);
```

I'm posting the working code based on you sample

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<StorageService> _services = new List<StorageService>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initializeListView();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadServices();
        listViewDisablableItemsServices.Columns.Add("Name",100);
        listViewDisablableItemsServices.Columns.Add("Status",100);
        foreach (var service in _services)
        {
            if (service.ServiceType == Constants.SERVICE_TYPE_STORAGE)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(service.Label);
                
                item.SubItems.Add(service.ErrorOrInterpretedError ?? Lang.GetString("Common_OK"));
                item.Tag = service;

                switch (service.ServiceName)
                {
                    case "google":
                        item.ImageIndex = 0;
                        break;
                    case "dropbox":
                        item.ImageIndex = 1;
                        break;
                    case "seeyou":
                        item.ImageIndex = 2;
                        break;
                }

                listViewDisablableItemsServices.Items.Add(item);

                if (!service.IsAuthenticatedAndAvailable)
                {
                    //listViewDisablableItemsServices.DisableItem(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadServices()
    {
        _services.Add(new StorageService
        {
            ServiceType = "Storage",
            Label = "Google",
            ServiceName = "google",
            IsAuthenticatedAndAvailable = false,
            ErrorOrInterpretedError = "Sign up required"
        });
        _services.Add(new StorageService
        {
            ServiceType = "Storage",
            Label = "Drop box",
            ServiceName = "dropbox",
            IsAuthenticatedAndAvailable = true
        });
        _services.Add(new StorageService
        {
            ServiceType = "Storage",
            Label = "See You",
            ServiceName = "seeyou",
            IsAuthenticatedAndAvailable = true
        });
    }

    private void initializeListView()
    {
        ImageList serviceLogoList = new ImageList
        {
            ImageSize = new Size(32, 32),
            ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
        };

        serviceLogoList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.drive_logo);
        serviceLogoList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.dropbox_logo);
        serviceLogoList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.seeyou_logo);

        listViewDisablableItemsServices.View = View.Details;
        listViewDisablableItemsServices.LargeImageList = serviceLogoList;
        listViewDisablableItemsServices.SmallImageList = serviceLogoList;
    }
}

class StorageService
{
    public string ServiceType { get; set; }

    public string ServiceName { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public string ErrorOrInterpretedError { get; set; }

    public bool IsAuthenticatedAndAvailable { get; set; }
}

class Constants
{
    public const string SERVICE_TYPE_STORAGE = "Storage";
}

class Lang
{
    public static string GetString(string key)
    {
        return "OK";
    }
}
}
```

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: The columns were already added in designer as mentioned in my original post above.

Comment: tomazj, you are right. I tried to add columns in the designer. Again the above code works for me. Still you are facing the same issue i think something extra in your designer code.  is my screen shot exactly you are looking .. right?

Comment: Yes, that is the result I want to achieve. My code & also yours works if I create a fresh new project, so I am now checking the environment variables etc. But I need to find out, why it doesn't work in the existing project.

Comment: Is it possible to remove your List View and add a fresh one ( for troubleshooting purpose only)

Comment: Also check the resource is properly rendering.

Comment: Removing and then re-adding the ListView component in my original code solved the issue. Thanks!